# How to make Patternizer pattern larger without losing quality

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

So I recently found a neat tool called Patternizer (maybe you've heard of it) which has an easy to use interface that creates patterns, which you can then instantly get the code for and use along with their js library.

So to properly use the library and the given code it requires a `canvas` element, so to make things easy I took their example element and id: `<canvas id="bgCanvas"></canvas>` and put that right after my `header` end tag.

The javascript for the simple pattern I created is:

```
bgCanvas.patternizer({
stripes : [
    {
        color: '#000000',
        rotation: 315,
        opacity: 50,
        mode: 'normal',
        width: 3,
        gap: 98,
        offset: 123
    },
    {
        color: '#000000',
        rotation: 45,
        opacity: 50,
        mode: 'normal',
        width: 3,
        gap: 98,
        offset: 123
    },
    {
        color: '#0d050a',
        rotation: 25,
        opacity: 60,
        mode: 'normal',
        width: 100,
        gap: 100,
        offset: 156
    },
    {
        color: '#0d050a',
        rotation: 335,
        opacity: 60,
        mode: 'normal',
        width: 100,
        gap: 100,
        offset: 156
    }
],
bg : '#231d1d'
});
```

Now. It works, however I noticed the canvas element is extremely small:
[image: The canvas at normal size]
As you can see, the canvas (in the top left) is much too small. So my first instinct was to change it's CSS to: `canvas {width: 100%; height: 100%;` to which I further added: `z-index: -1;position:absolute;}`
however heres what I got next:
[image: Canvas blown up!]
As you can see the canvas is much bigger, however, the pattern has simply blown up and loses it's previous scale and quality. Is there a simple fix to this in CSS I'm missing? Please help!

Thanks,

-- micoxion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to specify the canvas height and width in the html of the  element like stated on the patternizer docs.

https://info.patternizer.com/docs/

If what you need is a nice simple pattern i would recommend using a CSS only solution like the one found on http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/

[image: Some cool examples of CSS only textures]

Using js and a canvas for this is too much trouble.

EDIT: If you are using those patterns i recommend passing the code through https://autoprefixer.github.io so it has the correct prefixes and works in all browsers.

You can learn more about css patterns and techniques at https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/

Comment: I tried changing the width and height in the actual HTML. However it didn't really change the size all that much. I'll try out those other patterns, I wasn't completely sold on patternizer thankgoodness!

Comment: On a side note, are the patterns found on http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/ meant for a canvas element as well?

Comment: Those patterns can be used on any html element, if you need to use it as a canvas background you can just add it to its CSS like in: http://codepen.io/pfortes/pen/BQOejd

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a bunch